# Wordpress submiting data to my sql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I have designed my interface for submitting data to my database table but I am unsure as to how to go about doing this here is some of my code most of it is the same so once i know how to do it I can replicate it.

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

<table width="600">
<tr valign="top>">
    <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Track</th>
    <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Position</th>
    <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Driver</th>
    <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Class</th>
</tr>
<tr valign="top>">
    <td><input type="text" name="track" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="position" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="driver" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="class" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

what I want to do is input each of these values on there own into there table I have goggled the question and not found anything that was any help any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `submit` `<input>` tags?

Comment: Because each input doesn't need to be filled but I only want to send them one at a time and they all go to different tables

Comment: OK, this is not necessary, since any individual `submit` input will submit your form, sending *ALL* input data from the form to your processing script.

Comment: How much experience do you have writing PHP scripts? Also, this question isn't very clear on what you want to do, so I think the SO community needs a little more information on what you want to accomplish when the form is submitted.

Comment: when the form is submitted there should a new record created in the tables with that have had data submitted and no record in one that has not had any data submitted into it.

Comment: OK, so for example, the user submits data for `track` and `driver` but not for `position` or `class`. The `track` and `driver` tables will have new rows added, but `position` and `class` will not?

Comment: yes that's what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems here which need solving.

First of all, you only need one `<input>` of type `submit`. That can go outside of the table. Secondly, your `valign` attributes contain an extra `>` character.

```
    <table width="600">
    <tr valign="top">
        <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Track</th>
        <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Position</th>
        <thwidth="92" scope="row">Enter New Driver</th>
        <th width="92" scope="row">Enter New Class</th>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td><input type="text" name="track" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="position" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="driver" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="class" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The above code should go inside your `<form>` tags.

Once you have submitted the form, the data will be `POST`ed to *input.php*, the intent of which is to process the data and insert any new data to your tables (why you're doing it this way still remains a mystery, but I'll answer the question first).

*input.php* should look something like this:

```
<?php
    // I will ignore error handling here, but if you want a good tutorial on PHP PDOs, try http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html
    $pdoObj = new PDO("mysql:host=[yourhost];dbname=[yourdbname]", [db_username], [db_password]);

    // keep in mind that this code is WAY OPEN to SQL injection attacks, but this will at least give you an idea of how to get your code to function, if not securely.
    if(isset($_POST['track'])) {
        $pdoObj->exec("INSERT INTO tracks (name) VALUE ('" . $_POST['track'] . "')");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['position'])) {
        $pdoObj->exec("INSERT INTO positions (name) VALUE ('" . $_POST['position'] . "')");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['driver'])) {
        $pdoObj->exec("INSERT INTO drivers (name) VALUE ('" . $_POST['driver'] . "')");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['class'])) {
        $pdoObj->exec("INSERT INTO classes (name) VALUE ('" . $_POST['class'] . "')");
    }

    // some code here that will either display some copy or redirect the user to another page
```

**NOTE:**

It looks as though you're still new to web development, so I'll leave you with this: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is no joke. You **MUST ** defend against it otherwise you can lose EVERYTHING in your database.

Pick up a few books or tutorials on PHP, Wordpress and web development, in general. Talk to people in the community about best practices and try to get more pointers on how to do basic tasks you feel you're comfortable with. Then move on to more complex scenarios that test your competence. With enough experience, you'd be amazed at what you can make your web applications do.

Comment: I should also note that using a `<table>` to display form input is not a generally accepted "best practice." Use `<label>`s for your `<input>`s and style them using CSS. If you do this, you'll create less work for yourself in the long run.